# How can i implement Custom Seekbar in android?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

In android how can i customize the seekbar like this
[image]

.I want to apply the seekbar progress(0 to 360) is anyway to design above custom seek bar.anyone have an idea please tell me .Advance thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        mSeekBar.setThumb(R.drawable.thumb_image);
        mSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(R.drawable.progress_image);
        mSeekBar.setBackground(R.drawable.background_image);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.